# Change date format when echo in php

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code it works perfectly except I want the date on the buttons to be formatted as Thursday 15th, not 2019-08-15.
The dates are pulled from the MySQLI database where the date formate is 2019-08-15. I cannot change the select date format as I need the date format in the button value to match the format in the database. So I only want to change the format on the button.

[Here is a working example](https://gohs.no/mb/index.php)

I really appreciate all your help!!

```html
<?php
include 'DBController.php';
$db_handle = new DBController();
$countryResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM okm_concerts_2019 ORDER BY date ASC");
?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
       <div id="demo-grid">
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
 
                <?php
                        if (! empty($countryResult)) {
                            foreach ($countryResult as $key => $value) 
                            {
                                echo '<button name="country[]" value=' . $countryResult[$key]['date'] .'">' . $countryResult[$key]['date'] . '</button>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                
    
                <?php
                if (! empty($_POST['country'])) {
                    ?>
                    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        
                        <th><strong>Konsert</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Start</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Venue</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM okm_concerts_2019
                    JOIN okm_locations ON okm_concerts_2019.location_id = okm_locations.id"
                    ;
                    $i = 0;
                    $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['country']);
                    $selectedOption = "";
                    while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
                        $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['country'][$i] . "'";
                        if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
                            $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
                        }
                        
                        $i ++;
                    }
                    $query = $query . " WHERE date in (" . $selectedOption . ") ORDER BY time_start ASC";
                    
                    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
                 
                     
                }
                if (! empty($result)) {
                    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                        ?>
                
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to parse the date data thru `createFromFormat`  and then display it thru `format` .

You may use the following code to change the display format of your buttons (from YYYY-MM-DD to something like Thursday 15th, August 2019) :

```
<?php

$xstring=$countryResult[$key]['date'];

// example:  $xstring="2019-08-15";

$ndate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $xstring);

echo $ndate->format('l dS, F Y');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the dates directly in DB, using next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W, %D') FROM okm_concerts_2019 ORDER BY date ASC
```

Look [MySQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b10b4124269b9e79b86905d8db9c0757&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57) here

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
include 'DBController.php';
$db_handle = new DBController();
$countryResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM okm_concerts_2019 ORDER BY date ASC");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo-grid">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">

        <?php
        if (!empty($countryResult)) {
            foreach ($countryResult as $key => $value) {
                echo '<button name="country[]" value=' . $countryResult[$key]['date'] . '">' . date('l jS ', strtotime($countryResult[$key]['date'])) . '</button>';
            }
        }
        ?>


        <?php
        if (!empty($_POST['country'])) {
        ?>
        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">

            <thead>
            <tr>

                <th><strong>Konsert</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Start</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Venue</strong></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM okm_concerts_2019
                    JOIN okm_locations ON okm_concerts_2019.location_id = okm_locations.id";
$i = 0;
$selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['country']);
$selectedOption = "";
while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
    $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['country'][$i] . "'";
    if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
        $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
    }

    $i++;
}
$query = $query . " WHERE date in (" . $selectedOption . ") ORDER BY time_start ASC";

$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);


}
if (!empty($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        ?>


</body>
</html>
```

When you are displaying the date, you can format the date using the date function. Date function accepts the first parameter as the format of the date. In the second parameter, I am just converting the date to the Unix timestamp, so that the date can be easily converted into any format. You can view the supported [Date Format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) from here.